# attach missing source android

Tags: android, push-notification, push

I'm following [this guide](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) but I've remade it a bit; 
removed the first activity with all the email and name stuff. Basicly, what Ive done is:
an app with a button and a textview and when you press the button the regId pops up. So far so good, but when it comes to receiving the push itself there's no popup, no wake lock or anything, just a simple row in the "notification center" (dont really know what its called on android). heres the code:

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) 
    {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Errors:
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

> The constructor Notification(int, charSequence, long) is deprecated

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
The method setLatestEventInfo(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent) from the type Notification is deprecated
```

(the logCat comes out clean from errors)

when I open the declaration it says "The JAR file has no source attachment".
I've tried to add sources and googleing. but whatever i do it says

```
the source attachment does not contain the source for the file Notification.class
```

I believe that my problem with getting the message in the push is because of this. any ideas on how to fix it?

PS. I'm new to all this, please let me know if you need more of the code AND do tell me if I'm on the wrong track here!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your warning. The warning just says, that the method that you are using is deprecated since API level 11. For newer APIs you can(but you don't have to, it's just recommended) use Notification.Builder:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .build();
```

Edit: 
checking for current API:

```
int currentVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
int honeycombVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;

if (currentVersion >= honeycombVersion ){
    // Use Notification.Builder
} else{
    // Use Notification(int, charSequence, long)
}
```

Edit2:
You can use the Notification.Builder on lower APIs if you use the support lib.

Comment: first of all; thank you!
second; say I want to use that, how do I do it and do i have to rewrite anything else than 
>Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);?
really sorry if this is somewhat of a retarded question, but as i said, Im new to this stuff. I just want to receive a push with a popup that displays the message I send from my server (and maybe the icon thingy)

Comment: You can check for the API your App is running and depending on that you could use Notification.Builder or the Notification(int, charSequence, long) method.

Comment: Im using min API 8 and it seems like i need min 11 to do this.

Comment: If you use the compatibility notification builder you don't have to worry about API level

Comment: @A--C oh, didn't know that it was included in the support lib.

Comment: VERISON_CODE "cannot be resolved or is not a field" im sorry guys, i feel like such a pain in the ass right now, but this is not the things I'm used to.

Comment: Like A--C said, you dont't have to do it with this way :) use the support lib.

Comment: "Edit2: You can use the Notification.Builder on lower APIs if you use the support lib." : how to use the support lib ? What are the steps to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: If you are on Eclipse: Right click on the project > Android > Add suppor Libs @Regis